# PowerShell Windows Forms Wrapper

Tags: forms, powershell, controls, wrapper

In PowerShell it is quiet common to use  [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/winforms/) to build a User Interface for small cmdlets but the syntaxis required for this are often partly redundant and quiet verbose.  This leads to the question:
Is there a way to minimize the code required or does there exist a Windows Forms wrapper  for PowerShell to reduce the verbose and redundant syntaxis?
I am not looking for the [ShowUI](https://showui.codeplex.com/) as this solution is too heavy considering it based on [Windows Presentation Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/) (see also: [WPF vs WinForms)](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/about-wpf/wpf-vs-winforms/) and the fact that it concerns a PowerShell *module* which makes it more difficult to deploy it than a wrapper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a lot of cases a wrapper in not required to make your code less verbose, take e.g. the lengthy WinForms PowerShell script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772664/powershell-refresh-checkbox-array-from-combobox). Code pieces like this:

```
$System_Windows_Forms_Padding = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Padding
$System_Windows_Forms_Padding.All = 3
$System_Windows_Forms_Padding.Bottom = 3
$System_Windows_Forms_Padding.Left = 3
$System_Windows_Forms_Padding.Right = 3
$System_Windows_Forms_Padding.Top = 3
$Tab1.Padding = $System_Windows_Forms_Padding
```

Can easily be simplified in WinForms to a single line:

```
$Tab1.Padding = 3
```

And if the padding would be different for each side, PowerShell will automatically convert:

```
$Tab1.Padding = "4, 6, 4, 6"
```

<sub>*Note:* PowerShell does not convert `$Tab1.Padding = "3"` or `$Tab1.Padding = "4, 6"`</sub>

Nevertheless, the native way to create a windows form control is far from [DRY (don't repeat yourself) programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Although (multiple) properties can be added at creation (using:`New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{Location = "75, 120"; Size = "75, 23"}`) , *multiple* properties can't be set right away at a later state. Above that, it isn't quick and easy to add events<sup>1</sup>, child controls and container properties (as e.g. `RowSpan`), or any combination, intermediately at creation of a windows form control. Bottom line, you have to reference the windows form control over and over again to set its properties and more (with e.g. `$OKButton.<property> = ...` as in this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/creating-a-custom-input-box?view=powershell-5.1)) :

```
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
```

That's why I have created a reusable PowerShell Form Control wrapper that let's you minimize Windows Forms (WinForms) code to it's essence.

<sub>1) unless you use `On<event>` methods, see also: [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)</sub>

## [PowerShell Form-Control Wrapper](https://github.com/iRon7/Form-Control)

```
Function Form-Control {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName='Self')]param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]$Control = "Form",
        [Parameter(Position = 1)][HashTable]$Member = @{},
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AttachChild',  Mandatory = $false)][Windows.Forms.Control[]]$Add = @(),
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AttachParent', Mandatory = $false)][HashTable]$Set = @{},
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AttachParent', Mandatory = $false)][Alias("Parent")][Switch]$GetParent,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AttachParent', Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)][Windows.Forms.Control]$Container
    )
    If ($Control -isnot [Windows.Forms.Control]) {Try {$Control = New-Object Windows.Forms.$Control} Catch {$PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)}}
    $Styles = @{RowStyles = "RowStyle"; ColumnStyles = "ColumnStyle"}
    ForEach ($Key in $Member.Keys) {
        If ($Style = $Styles.$Key) {[Void]$Control.$Key.Clear()
            For ($i = 0; $i -lt $Member.$Key.Length; $i++) {[Void]$Control.$Key.Add((New-Object Windows.Forms.$Style($Member.$Key[$i])))}
        } Else {
            Switch (($Control | Get-Member $Key).MemberType) {
                "Property"  {$Control.$Key = $Member.$Key}
                "Method"    {Invoke-Expression "[Void](`$Control.$Key($($Member.$Key)))"}
                "Event"     {Invoke-Expression "`$Control.Add_$Key(`$Member.`$Key)"}
                Default     {Write-Error("The $($Control.GetType().Name) control doesn't have a '$Key' member.")}
            }
        }
    }
    $Add | ForEach {$Control.Controls.Add($_)}
    If ($Container) {$Container.Controls.Add($Control)}
    If ($Set) {$Set.Keys | ForEach {Invoke-Expression "`$Container.Set$_(`$Control, `$Set.`$_)"}}
    If ($GetParent) {$Container} Else {$Control}
}; Set-Alias Form Form-Control
```

### Syntax

**Creating a control**
`<System.Windows.Forms.Control> = Form-Control [-Control <String>] [-Member <HashTable>]`

**Modifying a control**
`<Void> = Form-Control [-Control <System.Windows.Forms.Control>] [-Member <HashTable>]`

**Adding a (new) control to a container**
`<System.Windows.Forms.Control> = Form-Control [-Control <String>|<System.Windows.Forms.Control>] [-Member <HashTable>] [-Add <System.Windows.Forms.Control[]>]`

**Piping a container to a (new) control**
`<System.Windows.Forms.Control> = <System.Windows.Forms.Control> | Form-Control [-Control <String>|<System.Windows.Forms.Control>] [-Member <HashTable>] [-Set <HashTable>] [-PassParent]`

### Parameters

**`-Control <String>|<System.Windows.Forms.Control>`** <sub>(position 0, default: `Form`)</sub>
The `-Control` parameter accepts either a Windows form control type name (`[String]`) or an existing form control (`[System.Windows.Forms.Control]`  ). Windows form control type names are like [`Form`, `Label`, `TextBox`, `Button`, `Panel`, `...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/windows-forms-controls-by-function), etc.
If a Windows form control type name (`[String]`) is supplied, the wrapper will create and return a new Windows form control with properties and settings as defined by the rest of the parameters.
If an existing Windows form control (`[System.Windows.Forms.Control]`  ) is supplied, the wrapper will update the existing Windows form control using the properties and settings as defined by the rest of the parameters.

**`-Member <HashTable>`** <sub>(position 1)</sub>
Sets property values, invokes methods and add events on a new or existing object.

- If the hash name represents [`property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the control, e.g.  `Size = "50, 50"`, the value will be assigned to the control property value.
- If the hash name represents [`method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) on the control, e.g. `Scale = {1.5, 1.5}`, the control method will be invoked using the value for arguments .
- If the hash name represents [`event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control_events(v=vs.110).aspx) on the control, take e.g. `Click = {$Form.Close()}`, the value ( `[ScriptBlock]`) will be added to the control events.

Two collection properties, `ColumnStyles` and `RowStyles`, are simplified especially for the [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control which is considered a general substitute for the WPF [Grid](https://msdn.microsoft.com//library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx) control:
 - The  [`ColumnStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutsettings.columnstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, clears all column widths and reset them with the [`ColumnStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.columnstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) array supplied by the hash value.
 - The [`RowStyles`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutsettings.rowstyles%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property, clears all row Heigths and reset them with the [`RowStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.rowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) array supplied by the hash value.
<sub>*Note:* If want to add or insert a single specific ColumnStyle or RowStyle item, you need to fallback on the native statement, as e.g.: `[Void]$Control.Control.ColumnStyles.Add((New-Object Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle("Percent", 100))`</sub>.

**`-Add <Array>`**
The `-Add`parameter adds one or more child controls to the current control.
<sub>*Note:* the `-add` parameter **cannot** be used if container is piped to the control.</sub>

**`-Container <System.Windows.Forms.Control>`** <sub>(from pipeline)</sub>
The parent container is usually provided from the pipeline:  `$ParentContainer | Form $ChildControl` and attached a (new) child control to the concerned container.

**`-Set <HashTable>`**
The `-Set`parameter sets (`SetCellPosition`, `SetColumn`, `SetColumnSpan`, `SetRow`, `SetRowSpan` and `SetStyle`) the specific child control properties related its parent panel container, e.g. .`Set RowSpan = 2`
<sub>*Note:* the `-set` column - and row parameters can only be used if a container is piped to the control.</sub>

**`-GetParent`**
By default the (child) control will be returned by the `form-control` function unless the `-GetParent` switch is supplied which will return the parent container instead.
<sub>*Note:* the `-set` column - and row parameters can only be used if a container is piped to the control.</sub>

### Examples

There are two way to setup the Windows Forms hierarchy:

1. Adding a (new) control to a container
2. Piping a container to a (new) control

**Adding a (new) control to a container**
For this example I have reworked the [Creating a Custom Input Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/creating-a-custom-input-box?view=powershell-5.1) at learn.microsoft.com using the PowerShell Form-Control wrapper:

```
$TextBox      = Form TextBox @{Location = "10, 40";   Size = "260, 20"}
$OKButton     = Form Button  @{Location = "75, 120";  Size = "75, 23"; Text = "OK";     DialogResult = "OK"}
$CancelButton = Form Button  @{Location = "150, 120"; Size = "75, 23"; Text = "Cancel"; DialogResult = "Cancel"}
$Result = (Form-Control Form @{
        Size = "300, 200"
        Text = "Data Entry Form"
        StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
        KeyPreview = $True
        Topmost = $True
        AcceptButton = $OKButton
        CancelButton = $CancelButton
    } -Add (
        (Form Label    @{Text = "Please enter the information below:"; Location = "10, 20"; Size = "280, 20"}),
        $TextBox, $OKButton, $CancelButton
    )
).ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $x = $TextBox.Text
    $x
}
```

<sub>*Note 1:* Although the adding controls appears more structured especially for small forms, the drawback is that can't invoke methods that relate to both the parent container and child control (like `-Set RowSpan`).</sub>
<sub>*Note 2:* You might easily get lost in open and close parenthesis if try build child (or even grandchild) controls directly in a parent container (like the above `Label` control). Besides it more difficult to reference such a child (e.g. `$OKButton` vs. `$Form.Controls["OKButton"]`, presuming you have set the button property `Name = "OKButton`)</sub>

**Piping a container to a (new) control**
For this example, I have created a user interface to test the `dock`property behavior. The form looks like this:

[image]

The PowerShell Form-Control code required for this:

```
$Form   = Form-Control Form @{Text = "Dock test"; StartPosition = "CenterScreen"; Padding = 4; Activated = {$Dock[0].Select()}}
$Table  = $Form  | Form TableLayoutPanel @{RowCount = 2; ColumnCount = 2; ColumnStyles = ("Percent", 50), "AutoSize"; Dock = "Fill"}
$Panel  = $Table | Form Panel @{Dock = "Fill"; BorderStyle = "FixedSingle"; BackColor = "Teal"} -Set @{RowSpan = 2}
$Button = $Panel | Form Button @{Location = "50, 50"; Size = "50, 50"; BackColor = "Silver"; Enabled = $False}
$Group  = $Table | Form GroupBox @{Text = "Dock"; AutoSize = $True}
$Flow   = $Group | Form FlowLayoutPanel @{AutoSize = $True; FlowDirection = "TopDown"; Dock = "Fill"; Padding = 4}
$Dock   = "None", "Top", "Left", "Bottom", "Right", "Fill" | ForEach {
    $Flow | Form RadioButton @{Text = $_; AutoSize = $True; Click = {$Button.Dock = $This.Text}}
}
$Close  = $Table | Form Button @{Text = "Close"; Dock = "Bottom"; Click = {$Form.Close()}}
$Form.ShowDialog()
```