# Label hidden by PictureBox in Powershell using Windows Forms

Tags: windows, forms, powershell

I have problem with `PictureBox`.

When I am docking `PictureBox` to the top right, it's hidding a part of label which is on the center of form. How I can bring to front label over `PictureBox`? I am thinking that problem is with docking declaration in both (`Image` and `Label` declaration), that's why it's hidden by `PictureBox`.

How I can do this properly?

**Form Declaration:**

```
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Something"
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.Topmost = $True
$Form.BackColor = "White"
$Form.Width = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width 
$Form.Height = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height - 50
#$Form.AutoSize = $True
$Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
$Form.ControlBox = $false
$Form.MinimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1280,1024)
$Form.MaximumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1920,1080)
```

**Image declaration:**

```
$Image = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("C:\xxx.png")
$pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox 
$pictureBox.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Right
$pictureBox.BackColor = "Transparent"
#$pictureBox.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right
$pictureBox.AutoSize = $True
$pictureBox.Image=$Image
$Form.Controls.Add($pictureBox)
```

**Label declaration:**

```
$redLabel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$redLabel1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($Form.Width, $Form.Height)
$redLabel1.AutoSize = $False
$redLabel1.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
$redLabel1.Dock = "Fill"
$redLabel1.Text = "Something"
$redLabel1.ForeColor = "Red"
$redLabel1.BackColor = "Transparent"
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 55, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$redLabel1.Font = $Font
$Form.Controls.Add($redLabel1)
```

**EDIT:**

`BringToFront()` method already tested and working in 50%. Text is not centered in forms, and when label meet `PictureBox`, text is wrapped.. I would like that label will somehow skip `PictureBox`..

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Add to your question what you have tried (`BringToFront()` or others methods)

Comment: Okay, I used this BringToFront() in wrong place.. After adding label Control it's working, but Label is not centered in form.. It's wrapped when it's meet picture box, and I would like to overwrite on pictureBox, to have it centered.. So it's seems that BringToFront fixed my problem in 50%..

Comment: Could you show what it looks like with a screenshot?

Comment: Added in question at the end.

Comment: Can you try this : `$redLabel1.WordWrap = $false`. It also should depend on the witdh of your label.

Comment: Does not work. Script don't work with this.

Comment: Do you use anchors to expand your label to the right side of the form? With this screenshot we can't see what is the border of the label.

Comment: I use only this for label what is upper in question.  I use fill in dock.

Comment: So you have to play with the width of the dock as it is the container of the label

Comment: You mean to assign form.width for dock?

Comment: Yes so the dock could expand to the form width. Be also sure that the label will expand too in the dock

Comment: I cannot manage this idea with width of form.. Also when I am put `Dock.Top` text is OK centered, picture does not bother but picture default is on the left, and I would like to have it on the right on Top..

Comment: There are 2 differents questions here, the one I answered was the `BringToFront()`method solution (you can mark it as accepted) and now the problem you have is the position of your different controls. You should open a new question for that.

Comment: @Manu thank you for help here, Below link to another question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180536/label-and-picturebox-position-collision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am quiet sure that your label isn't hidden by the picture, but just put aside this depends on the Z-Order of the image - and the label control (which doesn't show from the lose controls in the example):

- If you `fill dock` the first control and than `right dock` the second
  control, the first control will just fill the available the space that is
  leftover.
- If you `right dock` the first control and than `fill dock` second
  control. The second control will take all the space behind the first
  control

I have quickly modified my [Windows-Form wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46994239/1701026) example, to show this:

```
$Form    = Form-Control Form @{Text = "Dock test"; StartPosition = "CenterScreen"; Padding = 4}
$Table   = $Form  | Form TableLayoutPanel @{RowCount = 2; ColumnCount = 3; ColumnStyles = ("Percent", 50), "AutoSize", "AutoSize"; Dock = "Fill"}
$Panel   = $Table | Form Panel @{Dock = "Fill"; BorderStyle = "FixedSingle"; BackColor = "Teal"} -Set @{RowSpan = 2}
$Dock = ForEach ($i in 1..2) {
    $Button = $Panel | Form Button @{Location = "25, $(75 * $i - 50)";  Size = "50, 50"; BackColor = "Silver"; Enabled = $False; Text = $i}
    $Group  = $Table | Form GroupBox @{Text = "Dock $i"; AutoSize = $True}
    $Flow   = $Group | Form FlowLayoutPanel @{AutoSize = $True; FlowDirection = "TopDown"; Dock = "Fill"; Padding = 4}
    $Radio  = "None", "Top", "Left", "Bottom", "Right", "Fill" | ForEach {
        $Flow | Form RadioButton @{Text = $_; AutoSize = $True; Click = ([ScriptBlock]::Create("`$Dock[$($i - 1)].Button.Dock = `$This.Text"))}
    }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{Button = $Button; Group = $Group; Flow = $Flow; Radio = $Radio}
}
$Close  = $Table | Form Button @{Text = "Close"; Dock = "Bottom"; Click = {$Form.Close()}} -Set @{ColumnSpan = 2}
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

**Just a few examples:**

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

**Possible Solutions:**

- Do not dock the label but and position it or use anchors (See also:
  [What is the difference between Dock and
  Anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581535/what-is-the-difference-between-dock-and-anchor)
- use an other docking combination, e.g.: image `right` and label `Bottom`?

Comment: When I am using Anchor, label is disappearing and I don't know why... I cannot position it, because I would like that content will auto-resize when I am resizing window. Using another docking combination it's not solving my problem, because Label should be centered in the window, and on the bottom I would like to have button with some event.

Comment: Thank you for all answers and help. I did it.

For `pictureBox` I used Anchoring to "Top, Right" with Location related to Form width and height.
For `label` I used docking also with specified location. 
I removed `BringToFront` and `SendToBack`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called `Control.BringToFront` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx

So it should be in your code :

```
$redLabel1.BringToFront()
```

Comment: I already tried this method. It did not help, it is still cut.