# Label and Picturebox position collision

Tags: windows, forms, powershell

According to first question where I met another problem:
[Label hidden by PictureBox in Powershell using Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173882/label-hidden-by-picturebox-in-powershell-using-windows-forms?noredirect=1#comment81308827_47173882)
I created next question, to solve it.

Problem is that I use two different controls (`PictureBox` and `Label`) and I cannot fit `PictureBox` to Top Right corner of forms without problems with label which is centered in forms.

**Image declaration**

```
$Image = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("C:\xxx.png")
$pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox 
$pictureBox.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Right
$pictureBox.BackColor = "Transparent"
$pictureBox.AutoSize = $True
$pictureBox.Image=$Image
$Form.Controls.Add($pictureBox)
$pictureBox.SendToBack()
```

**Label declaration**

```
$redLabel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$redLabel1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($Form.Width, $Form.Height)
$redLabel1.AutoSize = $False
$redLabel1.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
$redLabel1.Dock = "Fill"
$redLabel1.Text = "Something"
$redLabel1.ForeColor = "Red"
$redLabel1.BackColor = "Transparent"
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 55, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$redLabel1.Font = $Font
$Form.Controls.Add($redLabel1)
$redLabel1.BringToFront()
```

At the moment I got something like this:

[image]

I think problem is with `Style.Dock`. Because when I am using `Style.Dock = "Top"` label is OK and centered without problems **but** `PictureBox` is on the **left side**. When I am use `Style.Dock = "Right"`, I get same what is in screenshot above.

When I am using `Style.Anchor`, picture is not showing, so it's not working or I am using it in wrong way.

Comment: Why are you setting the label location to the width and heighth of the form?